# Rails database configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How does rails know to connect to the dabase in my production env, I have no `database.yml` and no `DATABASE_URL` env variable set?

I do have a `POSTGRESQL_URL` env variable set.

Of course my database is postgres.

Comment: Maybe you have pg gem?

Comment: I do have the pg gem, does this make a difference? I searched their code and could not find a reference to an env variable.

Comment: A u sure you don't have database.yml file at all?

Comment: ssh'ed in the server and checked, also checked the env variables as in the description.

Comment: you should have the `database.yml` file anyway, if you use database in your rails project. It's in the `your_project\config` folder

Answer (score 0):

Actually my host provider (cloud66) generates the database.yml automatically if I don't post one.